# yun manage bridge manually

Tags: arduino-yun

in "Disabling the Bridge Script" of http://cylonjs.com/documentation/platforms/yun/

I did:

> Edit the /etc/inittab file to comment out the ttyATH0 line (put a # before it)

```
::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rcS S boot
::shutdown:/etc/init.d/rcS K shutdown
#ttyATH0::askfirst:/bin/ash --login
```

But I want to turn it on or off manually. Then I can program through WiFi if I want.

How to do that?